# Flatten repeated fields that contain a dot (.) in the column name

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to repeated fields and having a hard time with them, especially because they are saved in the database with a dot (.), which does not allow me to join the table to itself. Columns Online.TypeA, Online.TypeB & Online.TypeC are repeated fields.

This is what I should get:

[image]

This is what I get:

[image]

This is the SQL formula I am writing to get the results:

```
SELECT Id, Online.TypeA, Online.TypeB, Online.TypeC 
FROM FLATTEN(FLATTEN(FLATTEN([database.kind_table1],Online.TypeA),Online.TypeB),Online.TypeC)
GROUP BY Id, Online.TypeA, Online.TypeB, Online.TypeC  
ORDER BY Id, Online.TypeA, Online.TypeB, Online.TypeC
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to flatten one column and then join the table to itself by flattening the next column, by renaming the same table to A and B, but when writing column names as "a.Online.TypeA" I get an error. This never happened when including one dot in the column name, but I was forced to use two dots because of how the columns in the database are named and saved.

Since joining the table of itself seems out of the question and probably not the most effective solution, I wonder what I did wrong when writing the SQL formula

Comment: what your original data looks like? - provide schema!

Comment: It shows Id as a nullable integer, and the other three columns as repeated fields. There is a column named Online, which is registered as of "Record" type, which cannot be extracted. That is why all columns under this "Record" are named "Online.TypeA", "Online.TypeB", "Online.TypeC" and so forth. Does this answer your question?

Comment: not really! if you can check schema tab for table in BQ UI  - and put it in your question - that would help - the way you describe it above - still vague enough and can be interpreted in few different ways

Comment: Id - String - Nullable; Online - Record - Nullable; Online.TypeA - String - Repeated; Online.TypeB - String - Repeated; Online.TypeC - String - Repeated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is a little vague so below is based on how I interpreted it and is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  id, 
  STRUCT<TypeA STRING, TypeB STRING, TypeC STRING>(TypeA, TypeB, TypeC) Online
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(Online.TypeA) TypeA WITH OFFSET posA, 
UNNEST(Online.TypeB) TypeB WITH OFFSET posB,
UNNEST(Online.TypeC) TypeC WITH OFFSET posC
WHERE posA = posB AND posA = posC
```

This should give you an idea

You can test / play with it using below dummy data that hopefully matches to schema of your table

Data in `project.dataset.table`

```sql
Row id  Online.TypeA    Online.TypeB    Online.TypeC     
1   365 Single          Url             Link1        
        Single          Pdf             Link2    
        Single          Pdf             Link3    
        Single          Pdf             Link4
```

Query

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
SELECT 365 id, 
  STRUCT<TypeA ARRAY<STRING>, TypeB ARRAY<STRING>, TypeC ARRAY<STRING>>(
     ['Single','Single','Single','Single'], ['Url','Pdf','Pdf','Pdf'], ['Link1','Link2','Link3','Link4']
  ) Online
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  STRUCT<TypeA STRING, TypeB STRING, TypeC STRING>(TypeA, TypeB, TypeC) Online
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(Online.TypeA) TypeA WITH OFFSET posA, 
UNNEST(Online.TypeB) TypeB WITH OFFSET posB,
UNNEST(Online.TypeC) TypeC WITH OFFSET posC
WHERE posA = posB AND posA = posC
```

Result is as below

```sql
Row id  Online.TypeA    Online.TypeB    Online.TypeC     
1   365 Single          Url             Link1    
2   365 Single          Pdf             Link2    
3   365 Single          Pdf             Link3    
4   365 Single          Pdf             Link4
```

There is an assumption here that all three repeated fields have same number of items and they are match with each other based on position in array